# iOS devices hiding phone numbers in HTML pages

Tags: html, ios

I'm working on a email blast that displays a number to a federal company dealing with health.

Here's what my code in the section looks like:

```
<p style="margin: 1em 3em 0em 0em;color:color:#585A63;">
    Visit&nbsp;<a href="#" style="color:#0078ae;">a website</a> or call&nbsp;<span style="color:color:#585A63; display:block; text-decoration:none;">1-800-123-4567.</span>
</p>
```

This code displays as it should on all browsers and email services, but when I view it in iPhone 4S, 5, and iPad, all that shows up is:

```
Visit a website or call
```

The number is magically gone.  I've tried replacing the number with HTML entities as well, but no luck.  However if I type the number in twice, it will display the full first number and half of the second.  Any ideas about what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />` in your `head` tag.

---

Edit: Okay, so it's showing up for me: http://jsfiddle.net/XkssQ/show

My guess is that the container the phone number is in is too small, causing the new line to be truncated.

Comment: I'm not surprised it works on JSFiddle.  The code works fine on all non iphone and ipad devices.  I'll try the meta tag...

Comment: The fiddle was viewed on the iPhone simulator.